# Поиск и запуск нескольких скриптов sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, bash

Допустим у меня есть папка в которую я складываю скрипты для бд и их(скриптов) несколько.
Есть небольшой скрипт(bash) который применяет эти скрипты к базам командами типа:

```
psql -U user -h ip_addr name_db < ~/folder/scripts/1.sql
```

С конкретным указанием названия.
Необходимо чтоб скрипт, который запускает применение скриптов sql к базам, запускал все эти скрипты, вне зависимости от их количества и имени.
Объединить скрипты в один - не вариант(
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне реализовать эту функцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот это:

```
$ программа аргументы < файл
```

абсолютно идентично этому:

```
$ cat файл | программа аргументы
```

а в таком виде можно указать не один файл, а много:

```
$ cat файл1 файл2 файл3 | ...
```

и маску применить при необходимости/возможности:

```
$ cat файл* | ...
```